# How to find clone events in vCenter?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

How can i see all clone events, which occurred during the week in vCenter? I could not find log displaying clone event for all VMs around a datacenter.

Answer (score 0):

How about using PowerCLI cmdlets?

```
Get-EventReport -viewName user_events
```

Comment: I am missing this cmdlet. Should it be included in PowerCli 5.1?

Comment: I believe it is v5.0 of PowerCLI

Comment: What cmdlet replaced it in 5.1?

Comment: I think this command do exist in 5.1 also..refer http://pubs.vmware.com/view-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.view.integration.doc/view_integration_powershell.5.3.html